# Unknown output when getting response from POST request

Tags: objective-c, json, http, post, response

I am doing multiple POST requests in my app and one of them gives me an unknown response.

```
 Response is: {
    error = 0;
    questions =     (
                {
            a1 = "Gulf of Mexico";
            a2 = "Gulf of Carpenteria";
            a3 = "Gulf of Panama";
            a4 = "Gulf of Persia";
            id = 9;
            q = "What is the largest gulf in the world?";
        },
                {
            a1 = "\U0416\U0435\U043b\U044c\U043e \U0413\U0435\U043e\U0440\U0433\U0438\U0435\U0432";
            a2 = "\U0421\U0432\U0438\U043b\U0435\U043d \U0414\U0438\U043c\U0447\U0435\U0432\U0441\U043a\U0438";
            a3 = "\U0413\U0435\U043e\U0440\U0433\U0438 \U0427\U0435\U043b\U0435\U0432";
            a4 = "\U0426\U0435\U0446\U043a\U043e \U0421\U043f\U0435\U0446\U043a\U043e";
            id = 1;
            q = "\U041a\U043e\U0439 \U0435 \U0432\U043b\U0430\U0441\U0442\U0435\U043b\U0438\U043d\U044a\U0442 \U043d\U0430 \U0434\U0438\U0437\U0430\U0439\U043d\U0430?";
        } };
```

So as you see the first pair is fine.It gives me normal looking strings , but the other pair gives me weird characters which are supposed to say :

```
id: 1,
q: "Кой е властелинът на дизайна?",
a1: "Жельо Георгиев",
a2: "Свилен Димчевски",
a3: "Георги Челев",
a4: "Цецко Спецко"
},
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are doing what you want. It's just Unicode character encoded strings. U+0416, for, instance is the Cyrillic Capital Letter Zhe "Ж".

```
NSString *a1 = @"\u0416\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043e \u0413\u0435\u043e\u0440\u0433\u0438\u0435\u0432";
NSLog(@"%@", a1);
```

Prints "Жельо Георгиев" for me. (This needed lowercase U characters, though).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I found out the problem was from the PHP file. Where I called `json_encode()` function, the PHP file was saved with incorrect encoding. so I suggest to check the encoding. or in PHP set header like: `header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf8");`